# Get the from and to object from p2p_id in WordPress - WP Posts to Posts Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm now using [WP Posts to Posts](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) plugin in wordpress.

And now I made some links between posts and posts, users and users, or posts and users.

And in all three cases above, I want to do more with the p2p plugin.

For example, I may fetch the p2p_id first:

```
$users = get_users( array(
    'connected_type' => 'multiple_authors',
    'connected_items' => $post
) );

foreach($users as $user) {
    $p2p_id = $user->p2p_id;

    // ********** ATTENTION *********
    // Here, I got the p2p_id of the p2p object
    // In a general purpose, I want to get the 
    // from and to object from the p2p_id

}
```

So, how can I get the from and to object via the p2p_id? I've found over the documentation, but seemed no effective ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No other answers. So I finally found the answer myself from the source code:

File: `/wp-content/plugins/posts-to-posts/vender/scribu/lib-posts-to-posts/api.php`

Notice that there is a function: `p2p_get_connection($p2p_id)`

Then we call that function with a known `p2p_id`, an stdClass Object is returned, like the below:

```
object(stdClass)#2509 (4) {
  ["p2p_id"]=>
  string(1) "8"
  ["p2p_from"]=>
  string(2) "84"
  ["p2p_to"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["p2p_type"]=>
  string(10) "my_post_to_user"
}
```

Now that we can get the `p2p_from` id and `p2p_to` id, and we know it is a post or an user. We can construct the object.

So the finally solution may look like:

```
$conn = p2p_get_connection($this->p2p_id);
$from = get_post(intval($conn->p2p_from));
$to = new WP_User(intval($conn->p2p_to));
```

Still seemed not found in the documentation, hope it helps.